# withArray vs newArray

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

In the Haskell FFI, what is the essential difference between arrays allocated with `withArray` and `newArray`? I have function in c that works with `newArray` but segfaults with `withArray`. The working code looks bit like this:

```
a <- newArray items
fficall a
free a
```

The code that segfaults looks like this:

```
withArray items fficall
```

The segfault happens up when the ffi enters a blas function. Since I'm not allowed to show the c-code, the question is, *"please show me an example c-function that also segfaults with `withArray` but not with `newArray`."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, `newArray` ends up calling `malloc` to do the allocation, while `withArray` calls `allocaArray`, which ends up in `newAlignedPinnedByteArray#`.

Perhaps your function is relying on the memory being allocated by `malloc`, for example by attempting to `realloc` or `free` it?

Comment: If the memory gets `realloc`'d or `free`'d, haskell will still have the original address in `a`, so the heap won't take too kindly to the `free a`.

Comment: The troubling function doesn't seem to realloc or free anything passed to it. Any other ideas?

Comment: @aleator: Well it might simply be accessing memory outside the array, and on the C heap this just happens not to crash, while on the Haskell heap it does. Perhaps you should try running it through `valgrind`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `newArray` allocates the array on the heap using `mallocArray` (which will need to be free'd explicitly), but `withArray` allocates the array on the stack using `allocaArray` (assuming `alloca` behaves the way it does in C), which will be reclaimed when the calling function returns.  It is possible that your list is so large that it has caused a (drum roll) Stack Overflow.

Edit: Hmm, maybe not, it looks like `allocaArray` allocates a pinned array in the heap, using the haskell memory manager instead of the `C` heap.